# Postgres12.7 Replication - Terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command after primary or secondary is restarted

Tags: replication

The replication "breaks" after either the primary or secondary nodes are restarted:

This runs on ubuntu server 20.04 using ZFS ( see below for settings )

```
Replication that is broken Log:
2023-05-24 19:01:20.946 SAST [12] LOG:  entering standby mode
2023-05-24 19:01:21.259 SAST [12] LOG:  redo starts at 884/5101F808
2023-05-24 19:01:24.279 SAST [12] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 884/5325ECD0
2023-05-24 19:01:24.280 SAST [11] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2023-05-24 19:01:24.395 SAST [16] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 884/53000000 on timeline 1
2023-05-24 19:01:24.532 SAST [16] FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
```

Primary node:

```
NAME  PROPERTY                       VALUE                          SOURCE
tank  size                           32.7T                          -
tank  capacity                       27%                            -
tank  altroot                        -                              default
tank  health                         ONLINE                         -
tank  guid                           4542839108163411915            -
tank  version                        -                              default
tank  bootfs                         -                              default
tank  delegation                     on                             default
tank  autoreplace                    off                            default
tank  cachefile                      -                              default
tank  failmode                       wait                           default
tank  listsnapshots                  off                            default
tank  autoexpand                     off                            default
tank  dedupditto                     0                              default
tank  dedupratio                     1.00x                          -
tank  free                           23.6T                          -
tank  allocated                      9.10T                          -
tank  readonly                       off                            -
tank  ashift                         0                              default
tank  comment                        -                              default
tank  expandsize                     -                              -
tank  freeing                        0                              -
tank  fragmentation                  38%                            -
tank  leaked                         0                              -
tank  multihost                      off                            default
tank  checkpoint                     -                              -
tank  load_guid                      4075217078874960300            -
tank  autotrim                       off                            default
tank  feature@async_destroy          enabled                        local
tank  feature@empty_bpobj            active                         local
tank  feature@lz4_compress           active                         local
tank  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  enabled                        local
tank  feature@spacemap_histogram     active                         local
tank  feature@enabled_txg            active                         local
tank  feature@hole_birth             active                         local
tank  feature@extensible_dataset     active                         local
tank  feature@embedded_data          active                         local
tank  feature@bookmarks              enabled                        local
tank  feature@filesystem_limits      enabled                        local
tank  feature@large_blocks           enabled                        local
tank  feature@large_dnode            enabled                        local
tank  feature@sha512                 enabled                        local
tank  feature@skein                  enabled                        local
tank  feature@edonr                  enabled                        local
tank  feature@userobj_accounting     active                         local
tank  feature@encryption             enabled                        local
tank  feature@project_quota          active                         local
tank  feature@device_removal         enabled                        local
tank  feature@obsolete_counts        enabled                        local
tank  feature@zpool_checkpoint       enabled                        local
tank  feature@spacemap_v2            active                         local
tank  feature@allocation_classes     enabled                        local
tank  feature@resilver_defer         enabled                        local
tank  feature@bookmark_v2            enabled                        local
```

Secondary node:

```
NAME  PROPERTY                       VALUE                          SOURCE
tank  size                           101T                           -
tank  capacity                       73%                            -
tank  altroot                        -                              default
tank  health                         ONLINE                         -
tank  guid                           16783218233256186655           -
tank  version                        -                              default
tank  bootfs                         -                              default
tank  delegation                     on                             default
tank  autoreplace                    off                            default
tank  cachefile                      -                              default
tank  failmode                       wait                           default
tank  listsnapshots                  off                            default
tank  autoexpand                     off                            default
tank  dedupditto                     0                              default
tank  dedupratio                     1.00x                          -
tank  free                           26.4T                          -
tank  allocated                      74.6T                          -
tank  readonly                       off                            -
tank  ashift                         0                              default
tank  comment                        -                              default
tank  expandsize                     -                              -
tank  freeing                        0                              -
tank  fragmentation                  56%                            -
tank  leaked                         0                              -
tank  multihost                      off                            default
tank  feature@async_destroy          enabled                        local
tank  feature@empty_bpobj            active                         local
tank  feature@lz4_compress           active                         local
tank  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  enabled                        local
tank  feature@spacemap_histogram     active                         local
tank  feature@enabled_txg            active                         local
tank  feature@hole_birth             active                         local
tank  feature@extensible_dataset     active                         local
tank  feature@embedded_data          active                         local
tank  feature@bookmarks              enabled                        local
tank  feature@filesystem_limits      enabled                        local
tank  feature@large_blocks           enabled                        local
tank  feature@large_dnode            enabled                        local
tank  feature@sha512                 enabled                        local
tank  feature@skein                  enabled                        local
tank  feature@edonr                  enabled                        local
tank  feature@userobj_accounting     active                         local
```